# AWS Device farm notification, post test suite execution

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-device-farm

Is there any way to get notified in Slack, email or any other notification service when ever a scheduled test suite execution finishes in AWS Device farm. Except the way to poll device farm using CLI.

Comment: How is this being done locally?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AWS Device Farm currently doesn't have notification service. Customers can write a script to keep checking test results.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to use `post_test` section in the YAML file?

Comment: docs here -> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/devicefarm/latest/developerguide/custom-test-environments-extending.html